# Why Reset functionality is not working with dynamic dropdown in php

Tags: php, html

In the following code the Reset functionality is not working with this dropdown means onclick of Reset button textbox value get reset but the dropdown select is not reset to default value "select addvertize".

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" class="contact-form" name="deleteadvertize" id="deleteadvertize" action="" method="post">    
    <div class="row form-group">      
          <div class="col-xs-12">
             <label>Select Advertize</label>
              <div class="selector">

            <?php   
            include 'config.php' ;
            $result = mysql_query("select * from advertise");
            echo '<select id="advt_id" name="advt_id" class="full-width selector">';
            echo " <option value=''>Select One Advertize</option>";
            while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
            echo "<option value='" . $row['advt_id'] ."'>" . $row['advt_title'] ."</option>";
            }
            echo "</select>"; ?>
        </div>
        </div>
       </div>
   <div align="center">
        <button type="submit" class="btn-large">Submit</button>
        <button type="reset" class="btn-large">Reset</button>
   </div>
```

Comment: have you wrapped in <form></form>?

Comment: close form tag `</form>` at end

Answer (score 0):

```html
<form> 
<div class="row form-group">      
          <div class="col-xs-12">
             <label>Select Advertize</label>
              <div class="selector">
<select id="advt_id" name="advt_id" class="full-width selector">
    <option value=''>Select One Advertize</option>
    <option value='1'>Select One </option>
</select>
        </div>
        </div>
       </div>
   <div align="center">
        <button type="submit" class="btn-large">Submit</button>
        <button type="reset" class="btn-large">Reset</button>
   </div>
</form>
```

you need to you wrap your html in form tag

```
<form></form>
```

if still not work use jquery for this

```
$('select[name=advt_id] option').removeAttr('selected');
```

Answer (score 0):

Reset works when you have `<form></form>` tag. Please check you have form tag or not ? if not the add.

Comment: Offcource,I have added <form></form> tag and Reset is working for text boxes but not only for this dynamic dropdown.

Comment: Its working for static data I have a problem of Reset functionality with dynamic data.@Rana Soyab

Comment: you can share with us